# Git submodule update

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm not clear on what the following means (from the [Git submodule update](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) documentation):

> ...will make the submodules HEAD be detached, unless `--rebase` or `--merge` is specified...

How does `--rebase`/`--merge` change things?

My main use case is to have a bunch of central repositories, which I will embed via submodules into other repositories. I would like to be able to improve on these central repositories, either directly in their original location, or from within their embedding repositories (the ones that use them via submodule).

- From within these submodules, can I create branches/modifications and use push/pull just like I would in regular repositories, or are there things to be cautious about?
- How would I advance the submodule referenced commit from say (tagged) 1.0 to 1.1 (even though the head of the original repository is already at 2.0), or pick which branch's commit is used at all?

Comment: On the topic of "detached head", see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orighead-in-git and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237408/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-github-only-sends-about-half-the-commits for a practical example (not submodule-related, but still)

Comment: "you cannot modify the contents of the submodule from within the main project": yes, true. And I have edited my answer to shed some light on that apparent contradiction (non-modifiable submodule, that you still can modify from the main project repo!)

Answer (score 336, accepted):

This [GitPro page](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html) does summarize the consequence of a git submodule update nicely

> When you run `git submodule update`, it checks out the specific version of the project, but not within a branch. This is called having a detached head — it means the HEAD file points directly to a commit, not to a symbolic reference.
>   **The issue is that you generally don’t want to work in a detached head environment, because it’s easy to lose changes**.
>   If you do an initial submodule update, commit in that submodule directory without creating a branch to work in, and then run git submodule update again from the superproject without committing in the meantime, Git will overwrite your changes without telling you. Technically you won’t lose the work, but you won’t have a branch pointing to it, so it will be somewhat difficult to retrieve.

---

Note March 2013:

As mentioned in "[git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)", a submodule now (git1.8.2) can track a branch.

```
# add submodule to track master branch
git submodule add -b master [URL to Git repo];

# update your submodule
git submodule update --remote 
# or (with rebase)
git submodule update --rebase --remote
```

See "[`git submodule update --remote` vs `git pull`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621245/6309)".

[MindTooth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182868/mindtooth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103113/6309) illustrate a manual update (without local configuration):

```
git submodule -q foreach git pull -q origin master
```

In both cases, that will change the submodules references (the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the parent repo index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)), and you will need to add, commit and push said references from the main repo.
Next time you will clone that parent repo, it will populate the submodules to reflect those new SHA1 references.

The rest of this answer details the classic submodule feature (reference to a *fixed* commit, which is the all point behind the notion of a submodule).

---

> To avoid this issue, create a branch when you work in a submodule directory with git checkout -b work or something equivalent. When you do the submodule update a second time, it will still revert your work, but at least you have a pointer to get back to.
>
> Switching branches with submodules in them can also be tricky. If you create a new branch, add a submodule there, and then switch back to a branch without that submodule, you still have the submodule directory as an untracked directory:

---

So, to answer your questions:

> can I create branches/modifications and use push/pull just like I would in regular repos, or are there things to be cautious about?

You can create a branch and push modifications.

WARNING (from [Git Submodule Tutorial](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial)): Always publish (push) the submodule change before publishing (push) the change to the superproject that references it. If you forget to publish the submodule change, others won't be able to clone the repository.

> how would I advance the submodule referenced commit from say (tagged) 1.0 to 1.1 (even though the head of the original repo is already at 2.0)

The page "[Understanding Submodules](http://speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html)" can help

> Git submodules are implemented using two moving parts:
>
> - the `.gitmodules` file and
> - a special kind of tree object.

These together triangulate a specific revision of a specific repository which is checked out into a specific location in your project.

---

From the [git submodule page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

> you cannot modify the contents of the submodule from within the main project

100% correct: you cannot modify a submodule, only refer to one of its commits.

This is why, when you do modify a submodule from within the main project, you:

- need to commit and push *within* the submodule (to the upstream module), and
- then go up in your main project, and re-commit (in order for that main project to refer to the new submodule commit you just created and pushed)

A submodule enables you to have a  **[component-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/933735#933735)** development, where the main project only refers to specific commits of other components (here "other Git repositories declared as sub-modules").

A submodule is a marker (commit) to another Git repository which is not bound by the main project development cycle: it (the "other" Git repo) can evolves independently.
It is up to the main project to pick from that other repo whatever commit it needs.

However, should you want to, ***out of convenience***, modify one of those submodules directly from your main project, Git allows you to do that, provided you *first* publish those submodule modifications to its original Git repo, and *then* commit your main project refering to a *new* version of said submodule.

But the main idea remains: referencing specific components which:

- have their own lifecycle
- have their own set of tags
- have their own development

The list of specific commits you are refering to in your main project defines your **[configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899373/transferring-legacy-code-base-from-cvs-to-distributed-repository-e-g-git-or-mer/899428#899428)** (this is what ***Configuration*** Management is all about, englobing mere [Version Control System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056912/source-control-vs-revision-control/1056947#1056947))

If a component could really be developed *at the same time* as your main project (because any modification on the main project would involve modifying the sub-directory, and vice-versa), then it would be a "submodule" no more, but a subtree merge (also presented in the question [Transferring legacy code base from cvs to distributed repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899373/transferring-legacy-code-base-from-cvs-to-distributed-repository-e-g-git-or-mer/899428#899428)), linking the history of the two Git repo together.

Does that help understanding the true nature of Git Submodules?

Comment: by publishing you mean commiting?

Comment: @deepblue: yes, pushing. I have added the link to the tutorial which illustrates both the normal workflow and the incorrect one.

Comment: interesting, the git-submodule man page says that the contents of the git submodule directory cannot be modified "you cannot modify the contents of the submodule from within the main project"

Comment: Wow. That long an explanation for something that is principally that simple ought to be enough to scare any newcomer into just sticking with their svn:externals. ;-)

Comment: @conny: but, as I detail in " [Why are git submodules incompatible with svn externals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131912/why-are-git-submodules-incompatible-with-svn-externals/3132221#3132221) ", submodules are *fundamental* different and not compatible with `svn:externals`.

Comment: So, if each submodule is tied to the specific commit that _was_ the current one at the time when I added the submodule: how would I go about updating (pull/fetch) that submodule to include the latest changes from upstream? For example, I'm keeping my dotfiles in a repository and inside that, I've added things like vim-plugins as submodules, which I rarely intend to tamper with, but nevertheless want to update on regular intervals.

Comment: Sorry, to answer my own question, I gather cd'ing into the submodule and git checkout a sha, or git pull/fetch will do fine. Then commiting the update in the local repository.

Comment: @hced: You can also hit all submodules at once using `git submodule foreach`

Comment: .. still not getting it. is there an easier explanation on the web somewhere?

Comment: @Eugene it can help realizing this (git submodules) is really suited for component-based development (http://stackoverflow.com/a/933735/6309): what is the list of sources (with their exact revision) you need for your program to work? That list of precise point in history (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2300638/6309) of different groups of sources is represented by git submodules.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Since git 1.8.2, `git submodule update --remote`, provided the submodule is configured to follow a branch.

Comment: So this answer is incomplete then.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei I have edited the answer to make that option more visible.

Comment: I would delete this answer in favor of his, instead of incorporating it here, as it doesn't seem fair. Also, his comment is the correct solution, not his answer.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei no, I would not delete that answer! The all point of this answer is to point out what a submodule actually is. But yes, if you are after the git command to blindly copy-paste, without realizing what you are doing, then MindTooh's answer is the right one for you.

Comment: Where is `a special kind of tree object`?

Comment: @Itachi a gitlink: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59131783/6309

Comment: Overengineered answer

Answer (score 144):

To update each submodule, you could invoke the following command (at the root of the repository):

```
git submodule -q foreach git pull -q origin master
```

You can remove the *-q* option to follow the whole process.

Comment: If you just run `git submodule update --init --recursive` from the root, it will get all of them recursively and initialize them if they aren't already.

Comment: @SamSoffes That serves a different purpose entirely. Updating submodules will check out the submodules at the commit they are **currently** pointing to (not necessarily the latest commit). The solution in the above answer updates the commit of each submodule to the latest HEAD from origin/master.

Comment: My new method: `git submodule update --rebase --remote`

Answer (score 22):

To address the `--rebase` vs. `--merge` option:

Let's say you have super repository A and submodule B and want to do some work in submodule B. You've done your homework and know that after calling

`git submodule update`

you are in a HEAD-less state, so any commits you do at this point are hard to get back to. So, you've started work on a new branch in submodule B

```
cd B
git checkout -b bestIdeaForBEver
<do work>
```

Meanwhile, someone else in project A has decided that the latest and greatest version of B is really what A deserves. You, out of habit, merge the most recent changes down and update your submodules.

```
<in A>
git merge develop
git submodule update
```

Oh noes! You're back in a headless state again, probably because B is now pointing to the SHA associated with B's new tip, or some other commit. If only you had:

```
git merge develop
git submodule update --rebase

Fast-forwarded bestIdeaForBEver to b798edfdsf1191f8b140ea325685c4da19a9d437.
Submodule path 'B': rebased into 'b798ecsdf71191f8b140ea325685c4da19a9d437'
```

Now that best idea ever for B has been rebased onto the new commit, and more importantly, you are still on your development branch for B, not in a headless state!

(The `--merge` will merge changes from beforeUpdateSHA to afterUpdateSHA into your working branch, as opposed to rebasing your changes onto afterUpdateSHA.)

Answer (score 17):

Git 1.8.2 features a new option ,`--remote`, that will enable exactly this behavior. Running

```
git submodule update --rebase --remote
```

will fetch the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, rebase them, and check out the latest revision of the submodule. As [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) puts it:

> #### --remote
>
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.

This is equivalent to running `git pull` in each submodule, which is generally exactly what you want.

*(This was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21195182/865175).)*

Comment: It's not "yet another answer", as *NO* other answer has this command (prove me wrong). Other answers didn't work for me, this *comment* did, so I decided to post it as an answer while giving credit to the original owner. So consider removing your downvote.

Comment: There's a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/47836590?noredirect=1#comment45526594_9103113) by [MindTooth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182868/mindtooth) from 2015 saying this is what they do now.  You give no explanation of what this does (though you do mention MindTooth, but there's no real explanation of what you mean by that -— embedding URLs, as in this comment, would help). You don't say why it is a good idea.  You don't give any caveats.  This isn't, in my view, a helpful answer because it raises more questions than it resolves.

Comment: By that, I meant that **it works** instead of not working. Believe me, if more people were to see this answer, they would be glad, because **it works**. For things like this, most people just want to know the command that updates a git submodule, not how it's implemented.

Comment: I edited the answer to prove you wrong, also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194?noredirect=1#comment82694557_1979194 !!!

Comment: You've dramatically improved the answer — it would be sensible to do the editing before making comments so that I see your improvements, not the status quo ante.  I'd prefer to see a discussion of the `--rebase` too.  Reassuring that it works is good; explaining what it does helps too.

Comment: But you realise that is was clear for everybody that as of almost 2018, this was the correct command that achieves this simple task, right?

Comment: Definitively not "clear for everybody" — I don't realize that at all.  I didn't know it. I'm not sure how big of a minority I'm in (if, indeed, I'm in a minority).  The answer was not helpful to me because there was zero explanation of what it does.  It is better; it still ain't perfect.  It ain't my down-vote, so I can't undo it.  It is my delete vote; I'm trying to remember/discover how to cancel that.

Comment: A few years later, looking over this comment thread - a perfect example of an overzealous SO editor. Glad the OP of the answer stood up for himself. Wow.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, Wow, you're the first person to back me up. And I've taken a lot of downvotes, closed questions/answers, etc. for trying to help others.

Comment: "there was zero explanation of what it does" - it obviously updates git submodules, because that's what was asked 