# How to push existing git repository to github

Tags: git, github, version-control

No, it's not a dublicate.
I have existing git repository at my computer with multiple forks and commits. When I pushing it to github I just have a one RANDOM (because I do not know why THIS ONE) commit to remote repository and that's it. 
I tryed to move HEAD like it described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237408/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-github-only-sends-about-half-the-commits), but it takes me also to this random commit, which isn't even the last one and didn't tagged in any way.

So the questions:

1. Why it could behave like this?
2. How to upload all the files to remote repository rigth way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your questions:

1. It’s mainly caused you have many branches but not only one branch. When you use `git push`, it can only push the current branch to remote, other branches are not pushed absolutely.
2. If you want to push all files and branch to remote right away, you can use `git push --all`